# Is it possible for an Android process to do some work without any Android component (such as Activity, Service, Provider, Receiver)?

Tags: android, linux, process

> Typically, processes aren't expected to do any work when cached, but some apps might have custom features supported by processes that are expected to run while cached.

This quote comes from [Android Source Code Document](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/cached-apps-freezer#handling-custom-features) .
What is the *custom features* that can be running in cached processes. As I understand it, cached processes do not contain any running Android component, so does it mean that programs can be run without any component or cached processes may contain running components?

Answer (score 0):

I think so no because minimum **one activity** is required for run the android programme.

Comment: thats not true, we may create app with e.g. `Service` only or receive some broadcast and only `Toast` then

Comment: @snachmsm: Without activity how can you run the app?

Comment: called by another app/process? AIDL? common system event broadcast? (like `BOOT_COMPLETED`) plenty of options

Answer (score 0):

Know more about android fundamentals and android activities
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).